# How do I check if a Uint8Array is an encoded string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm looking for the following function that's fast and simple, whereby the input can either be raw data or an encoded string (using `TextEncoder`):

```
function isString(data: Uint8Array): boolean {
  ...
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to create this function yourself?

Comment: There is no way. All you could find out is if the data contains bytes that aren't mappable to UTF-8 characters, but you have no way of knowing if binary data that doesn't contain such bytes isn't meant to be text. How come these are mixed? Fix that instead: properly mark your data.

Answer (score 0):

Raw binary data is just bits and bytes. And those bytes could be interpreted as string if you want, but you have no way of knowing if that is *correct* and what the author of that data intended.

For example:

```
const binary = 0b01000001; // one byte
console.log(binary) // 65
console.log(String.fromCharCode(binary)) // "A"
```

That byte could be interpreted as a number, or as a string. And if all you have is that one byte then you cannot possibly know what the intent of that data would be.

---

A file, in comparison, has a standardized wrapper which contains structured data about the file, as well possibly a name with an extension that provides a hint about how to process that data. Somewhere in that structure is the actual raw data.

So this is a very different sort of thing.